# Istio Ingress Gateway for gRPC with SIMPLE TLS : Remote Reset Error

Tags: grpc, minikube, envoyproxy, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

We have been trying to Secure Gateways with SIMPLE TLS for our gRPC Backend which is deployed in Minikube (minikube version: v1.25.2) for now by following this [link](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/).

We were able to successfully access the gRPC service (gRPC server with .NET 6) over plaintext through Istio Ingress Gateway using grpcurl client.

But while we tried to use SIMPLE TLS, we have been experiencing -

```
 ERROR:
  Code: Unavailable
  Message: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote reset
```

Please find the steps -

- Created a certificate and a private key for sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com (Sample Domain for gRPC Server for Minikube)

> $ openssl req -out sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com.key -config sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.cnf

**sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.cnf**

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]
O   = sc-imcps organization
OU  = R&D
CN  = sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com
```

> $ openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -CA example.com.crt -CAkey example.com.key -set_serial 0 -in sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com.csr -out sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com.crt -extfile v3.ext

**v3.ext**:

```
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1 = 10.97.36.53
DNS.1 = sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com
```

- Create kubernetes secrets by following this command -

> $ kubectl create -n istio-system secret tls sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb-credential --key=sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com.key --cert=sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com.crt

- Created Gateway manifest. (kubectl apply -n foo -f gateway.yaml) [gateway.yaml is attached]
- Configure the gateway's traffic routes. by creating VirtualService definition [virtualservice.yaml is attached]
- Added Host Entry to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file -

> 10.97.36.53 sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com

- Client execution from host -

> $ grpcurl -v -H Host:sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com -d '{"AppName": "SC", "AppVersion": 1, "PID": 8132, "ContainerID": "asd-2", "CloudInternal": true}' -cacert example.com.crt -proto imcps.proto sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com:443 imcps.IMCPS/Init

**RESULT**:

```
Resolved method descriptor:
// Sends a greeting
rpc Init ( .imcps.ClientInfo ) returns ( .imcps.InitOutput );

Request metadata to send:
(empty)

Response headers received:
(empty)

Response trailers received:
content-type: application/grpc
date: Tue, 18 Oct 2022 10:32:07 GMT
server: istio-envoy
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 46
Sent 1 request and received 0 responses
ERROR:
  Code: Unavailable
  Message: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote reset
```

**NOTE**:

> $ istioctl version

> client version: 1.15.0
> control plane version: 1.15.0
> data plane version: 1.15.0 (5 proxies)

**Gateway** :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: sc-imcps-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb-credential
    hosts:
    - sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com
```

**Virtual Service**:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sc-imcps-bootstrap-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com
  gateways:
  - sc-imcps-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri: 
        prefix: /imcps.IMCPS/Init
    route:
    - destination:
        host: sc-imcps-bootstrap-svc
        port:
          number: 17080
```

Please find the logs from **istio-proxy** container from gRPC backend server pod -

```
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412448Z     debug   envoy http      [C190] new stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412530Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S8764333332205046325] request headers complete (end_stream=false):
':method', 'POST'
':scheme', 'https'
':path', '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
':authority', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com:443'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'user-agent', 'grpcurl/v1.8.6 grpc-go/1.44.1-dev'
'te', 'trailers'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.88.0.1'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-request-id', '0d9b8e43-da2e-4f99-bbd8-a5c0c56f799f'
'x-envoy-decorator-operation', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-svc.foo.svc.cluster.local:17080/imcps.IMCPS/Init*'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata', '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'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata-id', 'router~10.88.0.53~istio-ingressgateway-585d645855-brkx4.istio-system~istio-system.svc.cluster.local'
'x-envoy-attempt-count', '1'
'x-b3-traceid', '17b50b6247fe2fcbbc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-spanid', 'bc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-sampled', '0'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.412567Z     debug   envoy connection        [C190] current connecting state: false
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412674Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S8764333332205046325] cluster 'inbound|17080||' match for URL '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412692Z     debug   envoy upstream  transport socket match, socket default selected for host with address 10.244.120.108:17080
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412696Z     debug   envoy upstream  Created host 10.244.120.108:17080.
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412729Z     debug   envoy upstream  addHost() adding 10.244.120.108:17080
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412784Z     debug   envoy upstream  membership update for TLS cluster inbound|17080|| added 1 removed 0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412789Z     debug   envoy upstream  re-creating local LB for TLS cluster inbound|17080||
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412742Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S8764333332205046325] router decoding headers:
':method', 'POST'
':scheme', 'https'
':path', '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
':authority', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com:443'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'user-agent', 'grpcurl/v1.8.6 grpc-go/1.44.1-dev'
'te', 'trailers'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.88.0.1'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-request-id', '0d9b8e43-da2e-4f99-bbd8-a5c0c56f799f'
'x-envoy-attempt-count', '1'
'x-b3-traceid', '17b50b6247fe2fcbbc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-spanid', 'bc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-sampled', '0'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-forwarded-client-cert', 'By=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/default;Hash=dda6034f03e05bbb9d0183b80583ee9b5842670599dd86827c8f8b6a74060fa0;Subject="";URI=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.412802Z     debug   envoy upstream  membership update for TLS cluster inbound|17080|| added 1 removed 0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412804Z     debug   envoy upstream  re-creating local LB for TLS cluster inbound|17080||
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412809Z     debug   envoy pool      queueing stream due to no available connections (ready=0 busy=0 connecting=0)
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412813Z     debug   envoy pool      trying to create new connection
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412816Z     debug   envoy pool      creating a new connection (connecting=0)
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412869Z     debug   envoy http2     [C320] updating connection-level initial window size to 268435456
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412873Z     debug   envoy connection        [C320] current connecting state: true
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412875Z     debug   envoy client    [C320] connecting
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412877Z     debug   envoy connection        [C320] connecting to 10.244.120.108:17080
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412928Z     debug   envoy connection        [C320] connection in progress
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412939Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S8764333332205046325] request end stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412960Z     debug   envoy upstream  membership update for TLS cluster inbound|17080|| added 1 removed 0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412965Z     debug   envoy upstream  re-creating local LB for TLS cluster inbound|17080||
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412972Z     debug   envoy connection        [C320] connected
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412975Z     debug   envoy client    [C320] connected
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412979Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] attaching to next stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412981Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] creating stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.412988Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S8764333332205046325] pool ready
2022-10-18T10:04:29.517255Z     debug   envoy http2     [C320] stream 1 closed: 1
2022-10-18T10:04:29.517291Z     debug   envoy client    [C320] request reset
2022-10-18T10:04:29.517301Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] destroying stream: 0 remaining
2022-10-18T10:04:29.517318Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S8764333332205046325] upstream reset: reset reason: remote reset, transport failure reason:
2022-10-18T10:04:29.517366Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S8764333332205046325] Sending local reply with details upstream_reset_before_response_started{remote_reset}
2022-10-18T10:04:29.517607Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S8764333332205046325] encoding headers via codec (end_stream=true):
':status', '200'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'grpc-status', '14'
'grpc-message', 'upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote reset'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata', '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'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata-id', 'sidecar~10.244.120.108~sc-imcps-0.foo~foo.svc.cluster.local'
'date', 'Tue, 18 Oct 2022 10:04:29 GMT'
'server', 'istio-envoy'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.517689Z     debug   envoy http2     [C190] stream 3 closed: 0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.517832Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:664]::report() metricKey cache miss istio_response_messages_total , stat=12, recurrent=1
2022-10-18T10:04:29.517843Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:664]::report() metricKey cache miss istio_request_messages_total , stat=16, recurrent=1
2022-10-18T10:04:29.520398Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:664]::report() metricKey cache miss istio_requests_total , stat=24, recurrent=0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.522737Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:664]::report() metricKey cache miss istio_response_bytes , stat=18, recurrent=0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.526875Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:664]::report() metricKey cache miss istio_request_duration_milliseconds , stat=22, recurrent=0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.530799Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:664]::report() metricKey cache miss istio_request_bytes , stat=26, recurrent=0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.553171Z     debug   envoy http      [C190] new stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.553272Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S417038132095363947] request headers complete (end_stream=false):
':method', 'POST'
':scheme', 'https'
':path', '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
':authority', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com:443'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'user-agent', 'grpcurl/v1.8.6 grpc-go/1.44.1-dev'
'te', 'trailers'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.88.0.1'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-request-id', '0d9b8e43-da2e-4f99-bbd8-a5c0c56f799f'
'x-envoy-decorator-operation', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-svc.foo.svc.cluster.local:17080/imcps.IMCPS/Init*'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata', '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'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata-id', 'router~10.88.0.53~istio-ingressgateway-585d645855-brkx4.istio-system~istio-system.svc.cluster.local'
'x-envoy-attempt-count', '2'
'x-b3-traceid', '17b50b6247fe2fcbbc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-spanid', 'bc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-sampled', '0'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.553290Z     debug   envoy connection        [C190] current connecting state: false
2022-10-18T10:04:29.553412Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S417038132095363947] cluster 'inbound|17080||' match for URL '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
2022-10-18T10:04:29.553445Z     debug   envoy upstream  Using existing host 10.244.120.108:17080.
2022-10-18T10:04:29.553462Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S417038132095363947] router decoding headers:
':method', 'POST'
':scheme', 'https'
':path', '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
':authority', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com:443'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'user-agent', 'grpcurl/v1.8.6 grpc-go/1.44.1-dev'
'te', 'trailers'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.88.0.1'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-request-id', '0d9b8e43-da2e-4f99-bbd8-a5c0c56f799f'
'x-envoy-attempt-count', '2'
'x-b3-traceid', '17b50b6247fe2fcbbc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-spanid', 'bc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-sampled', '0'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-forwarded-client-cert', 'By=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/default;Hash=dda6034f03e05bbb9d0183b80583ee9b5842670599dd86827c8f8b6a74060fa0;Subject="";URI=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.553473Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] using existing fully connected connection
2022-10-18T10:04:29.553477Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] creating stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.553487Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S417038132095363947] pool ready
2022-10-18T10:04:29.553519Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S417038132095363947] request end stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554585Z     debug   envoy http2     [C320] stream 3 closed: 1
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554607Z     debug   envoy client    [C320] request reset
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554616Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] destroying stream: 0 remaining
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554631Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S417038132095363947] upstream reset: reset reason: remote reset, transport failure reason:
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554671Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S417038132095363947] Sending local reply with details upstream_reset_before_response_started{remote_reset}
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554756Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S417038132095363947] encoding headers via codec (end_stream=true):
':status', '200'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'grpc-status', '14'
'grpc-message', 'upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote reset'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata', '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'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata-id', 'sidecar~10.244.120.108~sc-imcps-0.foo~foo.svc.cluster.local'
'date', 'Tue, 18 Oct 2022 10:04:29 GMT'
'server', 'istio-envoy'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.554788Z     debug   envoy http2     [C190] stream 5 closed: 0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554893Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=12
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554903Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=16
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554905Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=24
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554914Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=18
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554917Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=22
2022-10-18T10:04:29.554919Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=26
2022-10-18T10:04:29.561521Z     debug   envoy http      [C190] new stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.561614Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S7465002415732961759] request headers complete (end_stream=false):
':method', 'POST'
':scheme', 'https'
':path', '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
':authority', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com:443'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'user-agent', 'grpcurl/v1.8.6 grpc-go/1.44.1-dev'
'te', 'trailers'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.88.0.1'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-request-id', '0d9b8e43-da2e-4f99-bbd8-a5c0c56f799f'
'x-envoy-decorator-operation', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-svc.foo.svc.cluster.local:17080/imcps.IMCPS/Init*'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata', 'ChQKDkFQUF9DT05UQUlORVJTEgIaAAoaCgpDTFVTVEVSX0lEEgwaCkt1YmVybmV0ZXMKHAoMSU5TVEFOQ0VfSVBTEgwaCjEwLjg4LjAuNTMKGQoNSVNUSU9fVkVSU0lPThIIGgYxLjE1LjAKvwMKBkxBQkVMUxK0AyqxAwodCgNhcHASFhoUaXN0aW8taW5ncmVzc2dhdGV3YXkKEwoFY2hhcnQSChoIZ2F0ZXdheXMKFAoIaGVyaXRhZ2USCBoGVGlsbGVyCjYKKWluc3RhbGwub3BlcmF0b3IuaXN0aW8uaW8vb3duaW5nLXJlc291cmNlEgkaB3Vua25vd24KGQoFaXN0aW8SEBoOaW5ncmVzc2dhdGV3YXkKGQoMaXN0aW8uaW8vcmV2EgkaB2RlZmF1bHQKMAobb3BlcmF0b3IuaXN0aW8uaW8vY29tcG9uZW50EhEaD0luZ3Jlc3NHYXRld2F5cwohChFwb2QtdGVtcGxhdGUtaGFzaBIMGgo1ODVkNjQ1ODU1ChIKB3JlbGVhc2USBxoFaXN0aW8KOQofc2VydmljZS5pc3Rpby5pby9jYW5vbmljYWwtbmFtZRIWGhRpc3Rpby1pbmdyZXNzZ2F0ZXdheQovCiNzZXJ2aWNlLmlzdGlvLmlvL2Nhbm9uaWNhbC1yZXZpc2lvbhIIGgZsYXRlc3QKIgoXc2lkZWNhci5pc3Rpby5pby9pbmplY3QSBxoFZmFsc2UKGgoHTUVTSF9JRBIPGg1jbHVzdGVyLmxvY2FsCi8KBE5BTUUSJxolaXN0aW8taW5ncmVzc2dhdGV3YXktNTg1ZDY0NTg1NS1icmt4NAobCglOQU1FU1BBQ0USDhoMaXN0aW8tc3lzdGVtCl0KBU9XTkVSElQaUmt1YmVybmV0ZXM6Ly9hcGlzL2FwcHMvdjEvbmFtZXNwYWNlcy9pc3Rpby1zeXN0ZW0vZGVwbG95bWVudHMvaXN0aW8taW5ncmVzc2dhdGV3YXkKFwoRUExBVEZPUk1fTUVUQURBVEESAioACicKDVdPUktMT0FEX05BTUUSFhoUaXN0aW8taW5ncmVzc2dhdGV3YXk='
'x-envoy-peer-metadata-id', 'router~10.88.0.53~istio-ingressgateway-585d645855-brkx4.istio-system~istio-system.svc.cluster.local'
'x-envoy-attempt-count', '3'
'x-b3-traceid', '17b50b6247fe2fcbbc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-spanid', 'bc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-sampled', '0'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.561647Z     debug   envoy connection        [C190] current connecting state: false
2022-10-18T10:04:29.561750Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S7465002415732961759] cluster 'inbound|17080||' match for URL '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
2022-10-18T10:04:29.561796Z     debug   envoy upstream  Using existing host 10.244.120.108:17080.
2022-10-18T10:04:29.561825Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S7465002415732961759] router decoding headers:
':method', 'POST'
':scheme', 'https'
':path', '/imcps.IMCPS/Init'
':authority', 'sc-imcps-bootstrap-lb.example.com:443'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'user-agent', 'grpcurl/v1.8.6 grpc-go/1.44.1-dev'
'te', 'trailers'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.88.0.1'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-request-id', '0d9b8e43-da2e-4f99-bbd8-a5c0c56f799f'
'x-envoy-attempt-count', '3'
'x-b3-traceid', '17b50b6247fe2fcbbc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-spanid', 'bc2b2057ef4db96d'
'x-b3-sampled', '0'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-forwarded-client-cert', 'By=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/foo/sa/default;Hash=dda6034f03e05bbb9d0183b80583ee9b5842670599dd86827c8f8b6a74060fa0;Subject="";URI=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.561841Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] using existing fully connected connection
2022-10-18T10:04:29.561844Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] creating stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.561850Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S7465002415732961759] pool ready
2022-10-18T10:04:29.561877Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S7465002415732961759] request end stream
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616003Z     debug   envoy http2     [C320] stream 5 closed: 1
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616037Z     debug   envoy client    [C320] request reset
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616045Z     debug   envoy pool      [C320] destroying stream: 0 remaining
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616057Z     debug   envoy router    [C190][S7465002415732961759] upstream reset: reset reason: remote reset, transport failure reason:
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616083Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S7465002415732961759] Sending local reply with details upstream_reset_before_response_started{remote_reset}
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616133Z     debug   envoy http      [C190][S7465002415732961759] encoding headers via codec (end_stream=true):
':status', '200'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'grpc-status', '14'
'grpc-message', 'upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote reset'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata', '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'
'x-envoy-peer-metadata-id', 'sidecar~10.244.120.108~sc-imcps-0.foo~foo.svc.cluster.local'
'date', 'Tue, 18 Oct 2022 10:04:29 GMT'
'server', 'istio-envoy'

2022-10-18T10:04:29.616158Z     debug   envoy http2     [C190] stream 7 closed: 0
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616256Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=12
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616265Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=16
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616267Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=24
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616270Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=18
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616272Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=22
2022-10-18T10:04:29.616274Z     debug   envoy wasm      wasm log stats_inbound stats_inbound: [extensions/stats/plugin.cc:645]::report() metricKey cache hit , stat=26
2022-10-18T10:04:29.664070Z     debug   envoy conn_handler      [C321] new connection from 192.168.1.13:40686
```

**PS** : We have successfully implemented SIMPLE and MUTUAL TLS for REST Services.

Any help will be very much appreciated? I am stuck here! Eventually, after this, we will need to setup **mTLS**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using gRPC server with .NET 6. And gRPC kestrel .NET 6 gRPC server is running in k8s under http transport, a minikube load balancer terminates SSL and sends request to the app with :scheme pseudo-header set to "https", but the actual transport is "http" results in this error. Here is the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30532). Also find the discussions here [thread-1](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/41102) and [thread-2](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/41102),

For my case, the solution is to add following Kestrel Configuration -

```
webBuilder.UseKestrel(opts =>
    {
        opts.AllowAlternateSchemes = true; 
    });
```